# Parallel algorithm to check if a sequence is sorted

Tags: multithreading, algorithm, sorting, parallel-processing

I need a parallel algorithm (cost optimal) to check if a given sequence of n numbers is sorted .

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For m threads, give each thread a chunk of n/m consecutive numbers with an overlap of 1 number. In each thread, check that that the sequence it is assigned is in sorted order. If all subsequences are sorted, then the entire sequence is sorted.

Examples:

```
[1, 4, 5, 6, 11, 42] => [1, 4, 5, 6*] and [6, 11, 42] with 2 threads
[1, 4, 5, 6, 11, 42] => [1, 4, 5*], [5, 6, 11*] and [11, 42] with 3 threads
```

* this is the overlap of 1.

This solution has complexity O(n/m).

Comment: You could be more efficient if we checked the boundary elements before splitting them (without overlap). Of course it would be more efficient for a smaller number of threads because the complexity becomes O(m + (n/m)); However this would form a better short circuit code to verify if the boundaries are sorted before launching the threads.